# How do I detect a stack overflow?

Tags: memory, stack, language-agnostic, out-of-memory, stack-overflow

- How do I detect whether my program has encountered an overflow of stack memory?
- How do I detect whether a specific thread of my program has encountered a stack overflow?
- Are there any significant signs, I am be able to take attention off?

  ---

I do not ask for how the operation system may find a stack overflow, I ask for how do I, as programmer or user, can find out that it has encountered a stack overflow.

Does my computer need to crash? Or is it happening "silently" in the background?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect possible / potential stack overflow problems in a c / c++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199747/how-to-detect-possible-potential-stack-overflow-problems-in-a-c-c-program)